# Trigger Event After Node Is Indexed

Tags: hooks, rules, search

I have a pretty basic Drupal 7 web site with Solr search (works great!).

I would now like to perform some "work" after each node is indexed with Solr.

First I tried creating a workflow rule but there is no event for "node has been indexed". Next I looked for Solr API hooks but came up empty handed.

Should I look at adding a hook somewhere in the PHP code? If so where? Or am I overlooking a more obvious solution?

Thanks

Comment: Which SOLR module are you using? You've tagged the question with both ;)

Comment: I have a solr stand-alone instance running and then Drupal connects to that using the Apache Solr Search module I believe. I search-api-solr adds API calls that developers can use to interface with Solr from within drupal code?

Answer (score 0):

Both Solr modules provide APIs:

- [Apache Solr Search](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21apachesolr%21apachesolr.api.php/7)
- [Search API Solr](https://drupal.org/project/search_api_solr)

But neither provide an after-node-update hook. If I had to guess I'd say it's both modules send data to Solr in batches, not one node at a time.

You might get some joy with the core [`hook_node_update_index()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_update_index/7):

> Act on a node being indexed for searching.
>
> This hook is invoked during search indexing, after node_load(), and after the result of node_view() is added as $node->rendered to the node object.

Comment: Learning as I go I'm building a drupal module to test your suggestion.

Comment: I think this hook is going to cause you the same problem you mentioned in the comments on the other answer. Patching the Solr module to provide your own hook might be the simplest solution. If you go down that route, [this question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994512/can-you-create-your-own-hook-in-drupal) should give you a good start

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is the ApacheSolr hook `hook_apachesolr_index_document_build`.  This gets fired when a node (or any entity type) is being processed before sending to solr.  Note the 'before', but this is called for every node whenever it is being indexed.

You could exit early from your hook by doing `if ($entity_type != 'node') { return $document; }` and you can also add or modify fields being sent to solr.  The ApacheSolr module processes created/updated nodes in batches (default 200) during each cron run.

Comment: This might work but I would have to kick off some sort of asynchronous event that ran my code which requires that the given node be indexed already. Race condition comes to mind... and the time to index a node might increase over time...

Comment: Sadly, I do not see a direct hook either. If you are comfortable changing the ApacheSolr module code, you could place a call to your own function there, or add your own hook.  Also, if you are so inclined you could do it from the Solr server end - writing a plugin that could request a drupal callback page (or just do what you want) when a node document is being inserted/updated.